# Adding an semi-transparent overlay to a column on hover while also removing the title

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a semi transparent overlay to my image on hover. I have written code in order to achieve the following effect:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQiC9.jpg

I was wondering how I could get rid of the "Data Warehouse" text only when the user hovers over the image. Here is my code:

CSS:

```
.overlay {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: #5e8cc9;
  z-index: 99;
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: raleway;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 100;
}

.title {
  z-index: 98;
}

.container1:hover .overlay {
  opacity: .9;
}

.container1:hover .title {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="overlay">
<div class="text">
<p style="text-align: center; font-size: 18px;">
<span style="color: #ffffff; font-weight: 200;">Cloud-Based | Single Tenant | Mosaic will operationalize warehouse in weeks with no start up cost | Mosaic takes care of all hosting, licensing and maintenance | Mosaic manages day to day operations | Highly flexible scalable warehouse model accommodates long-term evolution of data portfolio and sales operations | Mosaic implements new data sets and new requirements on demand</span></p>

</div>
</div>
<div class="title">
<h1 style="font-size: 56px; text-align: center; position: relative; top:     50%; line-height: 65px;"><span style="color: #ffffff; font-weight: 600;">Data     Warehouse</span></h1>
</div>
```

The only problem is that when I make the

```
.container1:hover .title {
opacity: 0;
}
```

, the title text and the overlay get removed.
I'm sure its a simple fix, but any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Your css is using the selector .container1 but you are not using that class anywhere in your html

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get your code work, but I dont know if this is the aswer you are looking for, if it is I can explain it much furder, anyway it is simple. First you have to target the element will be hovered and then target other element that will change his styles according on the hover of the element you declared. Example:

```
.element:hover .title{
   color:red;
}
```

this will cause wherever an user hover the element, the title inside that element will become red.

I give you a codepen with title hiding away, and with overlay and title hiding away https://codepen.io/Kristain/pen/QgeZJd

Glad if I help

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the biggest issue is you need to select based on a common parent. So the text that fades in and the text that fades out need to both be in the same element, lets call it 'box' then you would do `.box:hover .title { opacity: 0; }` and `.box:hover .text { opacity: 1; }`

Here's an example.

```css
body { background-color: #000; }
.box {
  background: url('https://unsplash.it/200') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}
.box__title {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 56px;
  font-weight: 600;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  line-height: 1em;
  position: relative;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in;
  width: 100%;
}
.box__text {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in;
  width: 100%;
}
.box:hover .box__text {
  opacity: 1;
}
.box:hover .box__title {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="box__title">Data Warehouse</div>
  <div class="box__text">Cloud-Based | Single Tenant | Mosaic will operationalize warehouse in weeks with no start up cost | Mosaic takes care of all hosting, licensing and maintenance | Mosaic manages day to day operations | Highly flexible scalable warehouse model accommodates long-term evolution of data portfolio and sales operations | Mosaic implements new data sets and new requirements on demand</div>
</div>
```